# How to refresh a tkinter text box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a script, a small function which adds 1 to the int `x` and used it in the text box as the size. The problem is that the text box doesn't read the new size of the font after i call the function so how do i refresh the text box for it to use the latest `x` value?

```
import re
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = Tk()
root.title('Notepad')
root.iconbitmap('C:/Users/Hero/Documents/Visual Studio code/My project/notes.ico')
root.geometry("500x500")

root.tk.call("source", "C:/Users/Hero/Documents/Visual Studio code/My project/azure.tcl")
root.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")

x = 20

def change_theme():
    if root.tk.call("ttk::style", "theme", "use") == "azure-dark":
        root.tk.call("set_theme", "light")
    else:
        root.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")

def font_size():
    global x
    x = x + 1
    print(x)
    text=Text(root, font=("Georgia", x), yscrollcommand=scroll.set, bg='#292929', height=1, width=1)
    

style=ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('azure-dark')
style.configure("Vertical.TScrollbar", background="grey", bordercolor="black", arrowcolor="white")

barframe = Frame()
barframe.pack(side=BOTTOM)

fonts = ttk.Button(barframe, text='Size and Font', width=15, style='Accent.TButton', command=font_size)
calculater = ttk.Button(root, text='Calculater', width=15, style='Accent.TButton')
fonts.grid(row=0, column=0)

scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical')
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')

text=Text(root, font=("Georgia", x), yscrollcommand=scroll.set, bg='#292929', height=1, width=1)
scroll.config(command=text.yview)
text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to change the configuration of the global `text`, not create a new local variable that never gets packed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `text = Text(...)` in your `font_size` function, which creates a new `Text`, you want to update the one that already exists.

```py
text.config(font=("Georgia", x))
```

Answer (score 2):

for change parameter must be  used  method  `config` or `itemconfig` for [more detail](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-reconfigure-tkinter-canvas-items)

```py
label=Label(text="hello world")

label.config(text="hello")

#in the same way
text=Text(root, font=("Georgia", x), yscrollcommand=scroll.set, bg='#292929', height=1, width=1)
text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
text.config(font=("Georgia", x))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).